# Can we post and redirect in a single operation from ASP.NET Codebehind?

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, redirect, webforms

A colleague has been developing an ASP.NET Web Forms application and he wants to submit information entered in a form from one page to another.

He asked me how it should be done, and despite not having a whole lot of experience with ASP.NET webforms, I answered it could be done like a simple HTML form post. However we are having a hard time implementing this in practice.

Both pages use the same Master Page, and the masterpage defines one `<form>` element. In the first page (or should I say, *webform*), there are `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ...>` elements and one `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ...>`. The button has `OnClick="lkbSend_Click"`.

In the codebehind (at the `lkbSend_Click` method), my colleague has to perform some pre-validation before submitting the information to the second page, hence using the `PostBackUrl` attribute for the LinkButton (first suggestion I found<sup>[1]</sup>, <sup>[2]</sup>) is not allowed, at least not from the `aspx` markup.

After more research we found suggestions<sup>[3]</sup> of doing a POST request followed by a redirect from the codebehind, but this doesn't work as we'd expect because these are two separate operations - the POST works alright, but when the user is redirected we no longer have `Request.Form["..."]`.

A third idea I came across<sup>[4]</sup> was adding the information to `Context.Items` and then using `Server.Transfer`; however we can't do that because the URL must change between pages.

For the time being my colleague is storing the form contents in `Context.Session`, but neither of us are happy with that approach as we find it doesn't scale so well.

I thought about changing the linkbutton's `PostBackUrl` property from the codebehind (at the end of the `lkbSend_Click` method) and then invoking a new form POST. Would that be possible, and if so, how?

I tried:

```
btnSendEmail.PostBackUrl = "<another page's URL>";
btnSendEmail_OnClick(sender, e);
```

But, not with much surprise, this generates a `StackOverflowException`.

In case that wouldn't be possible, is there another way to go?

Additional notes:

1. I gather there isn't a *`PostUrl`* form property, or is there?
2. I've just read<sup>[5]</sup> that *"You definitely cannot POST and redirect in the same time"*. Would that be correct? If so, how does HTML's `<form action="...">` (and presumably, ASP's `PostBackUrl` as well) work?
3. The data must be POSTed (i.e. not encoded in the URI string as in a GET request).
4. I've seen a suggestion that a HTTP 307 redirect would do the trick<sup>[6]</sup>, but it is not reliable.

Thanks,

<sub>[1] [How to pass information between web forms in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20866009/3258851)</sub>
<sub>[2] [asp.net 4.5 PreviousPage is null with cross page posting using a master page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29240038/3258851)</sub>
<sub>[3] [Redirect to another page using Post method from Code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2258864/3258851)</sub>
<sub>[4] [Action PostBackUrl Programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6536375/3258851)</sub>
<sub>[5] [Can I set a POST variable before redirecting to a new page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5625455/3258851)</sub>
<sub>[6] [A good way to redirect with a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2604530/3258851)</sub>

Comment: Did you look at/try any of the other answers on the various questions you've looked at? For instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802848/215552) on [Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46582/215552) shows simply constructing a normal HTML `form` with an appropriate `action` attribute...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, I seen *all* of them and tried some - not that one in particular, thought, because it's not straightforward enough (mostly, the same reason we're not at ease using `session`). Also, that's not strictly codebehind - although at this point I suspect this **can't** be done in pure codebehind. And if that's the case, I would prefer changing the original form's `action` (via javascript) and forcing a new post instead of marshalling every single form element into a new `form` individually.